# Why is Ubuntu download hanging for hours?

Tags: downloads

This is the fifth time in 3 nights I have started to download `Ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso`. Each time it downloads the first 20 - 24%. Then it hangs for hours with no progress (I have even left this running unattended for up to 5 hours - no movement).

I am not bothered particularly by the speed or lack of it. If it would just finish - I need this Ubuntu version for a University Course I have just started.

Co-incidentally windows has just downloaded 14 large updates in less than 4 minutes.....

Comment: Have you tried using an alternate download such as a torrent?

Comment: It's not the server, it's your isp.  Vote with your wallet and switch.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to you to download it via Bittorrent.

In Ubuntu page, you can chose Torrent file, and its speed is very good.

You can select it from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You are better off using a torrent client such as [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/utorrent-free). ***NOTE:*** Downloading Ubuntu via µTorrent would not be considered illegal.
The download link for the Ubuntu torrent file can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).